# How come there is no wp-content directory in wp theme

Tags: customization

I am using Mochhost.com as my Hosting. Recently I have downloaded a free wp theme from wordpress.org. I unzipped the theme and I uploaded to my site at http://thegoods.info into my root directory, that is, public_html  with Filezilla. Now my question is, I am unable to see the wp-content directory both in the Filezilla part as well as in my local machine. At first I thought I could not downloaded the theme properly from Wordpress.org. And for a double check I downloaded another free theme from Wordpress.org and I unzipped it and I saw the same thing, NO WP-CONTENT directory.

Previously I downloaded many wp themes from Wordpress.org and I purchased WP themes. But always there was this directory. I need to locate this directory in order to edit the file wp-config-sample.php file for entering my data bases there and rename this file as wp-confiq.php. To start this process I need this directory wp-content first.

Could you please help me to solve my issue. Would appreciate much for that.

Thanks
Kamrul
kochi97

Answer (score 0):

wp-config-sample.php lives in your public_html directory.

Wordpress installation is normally called latest.zip and available at http://wordpress.org/latest.zip

If you are using Filezila, get that zip file, unzip locally and upload the contents of the zip file to your public_html directory.

Edit wp-config-sample.php, rename it to wp-config.php and point your browser to http://thegoods.info You should see the 5 minute install instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are mistaken about how WordPress themes work, or what comes bundled with a theme. You can't just download the theme and drop it into the web root directory, which is what it sounds like you did. Your theme operates inside the context of the WordPress core. You need to [download WordPress itself](https://wordpress.org/download/), and install it. That is the part that goes in the web root directory. Inside the WordPress files there should be a `wp-content` directory. After you have installed WordPress, then download your theme and put it in the `wp-content` directory.